# extjs 4 tree select a specific node by its internal id (not by record index)

Tags: select, tree, extjs4, treepanel

I'm trying to sync a dataview (explorer window) with a tree (directory tree).
When I click on an element on my dataview, I'd like the same node gets selected on the tree

The problem is that using the 
`tree.getSelectionModel().select(index)`
doesn't allow me to select the node by its internal id (the id I provided in my treestore), but only by the record index...
So I just can't sync both views...
There would be the solution of the expandPath(), but my treestore is fed by a relational database (id,name,parent_id etc..), so finding the full path is(or could be) a heavy load for the server (I'd like to avoid to have to provide any path...).

Basically I would like to be able to say "expand the node where the "id= " (or any other key/value of the treestore).

Is it possible ? Is there any workaround ?

Thank you for reading me !

Answer (score 9):

The tree.getSelectionModel().select(record) function can accept a record instance instead of an index. I would do something like this:

```
var record = tree.getRootNode().findChild('id_name','record_id',true);
tree.getSelectionModel().select(record);
```

for more info on the findChild function, check out the NodeInterface docs here:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-findChild

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `selecteditemtree.data.id` for this.